# Преобразовать координаты мыши окна в глобальные кординаты

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, экран

Привет всем как я могу преобразовать координаты из окна в глобальные? Допустим у меня есть окно(HWND) я нажимаю левую кнопку мыши, получаю координаты клика.

```
POINT Point;
Point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
Point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

Следующее, что я делаю - это хочу преобразовать координаты для HWND_DESKTOP. Почитал на MSDN Про ClientToScreen и MapWindowPoints. Не одна из функций не решила проблему.

```
POINT Point;
Point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
Point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);  

MapWindowPoints(hWnd, HWND_DESKTOP, &Point, 1);
//Либо
ClientToScreen(hWnd, &Point);
//Не то не другое не решает проблему! Курсор не устанавливается
//в нужную область..
SetCursorPos(Point.x, Point.y);
```

Полный код :

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
case WM_RBUTTONUP:
{    
    POINT Point;
    Point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    Point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);  

    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, HWND_DESKTOP, &Point, 1);
    //ScreenToClient(hWnd, &Point);

    SetCursorPos(Point.x, Point.y);

    printf("Send %d-%d\r\n", Point.x, Point.y);      
}
```

[image: Демонстрация что я хочу сделать..]

Comment: GetCursorPos может помочь, если нужны глобальные координаты

Comment: Зачем вообще перемещать курсор куда-либо, опираясь на перемещения этого же курсора? Преобразования работают правильно, оба варианта. Вы лучше объясните, что хотите сделать с этими координатами.

Comment: При клики мышкой допустим в окне размером 200x200 мы получаем позицию курсора (x, y); Далее у нас есть сам рабочий стол размером 700x700 не суть важно. Нужно отобразить (x, y) => (x', y') сохраняя пропорции. Иными словами если мы кликнули в окне 200x200 в координатах x = 25, y = 25; мы должны преобразовать координаты но уже для 700x700

Answer (score 3):

> При клики мышкой допустим в окне размером 200x200 мы получаем позицию курсора (x, y); Далее у нас есть сам рабочий стол размером 700x700 не суть важно. Нужно отобразить (x, y) => (x', y') сохраняя пропорции. Иными словами если мы кликнули в окне 200x200 в координатах x = 25, y = 25; мы должны преобразовать координаты но уже для 700x700

Это уже немного другая заача, и она не решается через MapWindowPoints/ClientToScreen

Вспоминайте правила пропорции:

```
x  == 200
x' == 700

x' - ? => (700 * x) / 200
```

Если Вы очень хотите использовать тут `WinApi`, то могу предложить полезную функцию `MulDiv`, как раз для таких случаев:

```
RECT rw;
POINT Point;
Point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
Point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rw);
MapWindowPoints(hwnd, HWND_DESKTOP, &Point, 1);
x' = MulDiv(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), Point.x - rw.left, rw.right - rw.left);
y' = MulDiv(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), Point.y - rw.top, rw.bottom - rw.top);
```

Здесь `MapWindowPoints` я использовал только для того, чтобы получить координаты именно в пределах окна, а не его клиентской области.

Comment: Очень близко но не то...Задача сводится к тому, если вы играли в игры по типу WarCraft/StarCraft Там есть мини-мапа, и сама карта на которой происходит игра. У меня в качестве мини-мапы выступает мое приложение с окном (HWND) и есть непосредственно раб.стол HWND_DESKTOP. Это окно выступает уменьшенной моделью реального рабочего стола. При клике в некоторую область в этом окне, курсор должен перемещаться в положение на рабочем столе.

Comment: Так ведь я эту задачу Вам и решил: задайте Вашему окну размеры, пропорциональные раб. столу и получите ту же самую миникарту. Или Вы хотите, чтобы эти пропорции здесь учитывались автоматически, независимо от размера окна hwnd?

Comment: да, независимо от размера hwnd...MulDiv по мойму лишняя функция все это должна выполнять MapWindowPoints, но где-то затык...